# Relay subscription error: Expected null to be a GraphQL composite type

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I want to create a subscription, but when I am compiling to relay I am getting this error:

`ERROR:
Expected null to be a GraphQL composite type.`

I think what my *graphql* definition is wrong, but I have no clue about how to check it. Sadly the documentation at relay site is too simple. Do you know what are the rules in order to create a proper graphql for a subscription?

Comment: Can you post your current schema?

Comment: I found the solution, I need to create the subscription type in my schema.graphql, but I don't know what are the rules to create the subscription types. Right now I adapted an example, and it is working.
Do you know where to get those rules?

Answer (score 0):

In theory the file schema.graphql is autogenerated, but I can't find how to add a subscription in it from tools.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/react-relay/7-subscriptions/) and manually added a type for the subscriptions adapting this [schema](https://www.graphqlbin.com/hn-relay-full.graphql) file to my case.
This is my final schema file:

```
type Subscription {
  Story(filter: StorySubscriptionFilter): StorySubscriptionPayload
}

input StorySubscriptionFilter {
  mutation_in: [_ModelMutationType!]
}

type StorySubscriptionPayload {
  mutation: _ModelMutationType!
  node: Story
  updatedFields: [String!]
  previousValues: StoryPreviousValues
}

enum _ModelMutationType {
  CREATED
  UPDATED
  DELETED
}

type StoryPreviousValues {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  id: ID!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Expected null to be a GraphQL composite type.

Above error simply means that you are missing a type in the schema you are using for compiling that you are using in your code.

One of the easiest way to get the latest updated schema matching with the GraphQL server is to use `get-graphql-schema`

```
get-graphql-schema graphql server url > schema.graphql
```

replace *graphql server url* with the actual url

and then use the updated `schema.graphql` for compiling

```
yarn relay-compiler --src ./src --schema schema.graphql
```

Comment: My problema was what the subscriptions were not generated by generate schema command.